# MS SQL previews more columns than necessary

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, exception, dataset, constraints

I defined tables `Foo`, `Bar` and `FooToBar` in `WebControlling.xsd`.
An adapter method `GetAllFoos` in `FooToBar` has to return all `Name`, `Country` and `Year` from `Foo`.
Another `GetAllUnboundBars` returns `Name` and `Year` from `Bar` where `Bar.ID` is not in `FooToBar`.
For `GetAllFoos` in `FooToBar` I wrote:

```
SELECT   ID AS FooID, FooName, FooCountry, FooYear
FROM         Foo
```

When I use the preview Tool it also displays the values from `FooToBar`.

```
| {some-id-Foo} | John Doe | US | 1988 | -empty FooToBar ID- | -empty Bar FK- |
```

The issue I'm having with this is that I get an Error in `FooToBar.cs` at `Adapter.GetAllFoos()`:

> System.Data.ConstraintException: 'Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.'

Which, altough I never asked for it, is correct. `FooToBarID` and `BarID` can't be empty.
Why does the adapter still send them? How can I supress it?

Preview Tool:
[image]
Adapter Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns all available ProjectsOverall
/// </summary>
[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
public WebControlling.ProjectsOverallToProjectsDataTable GetAvailableProjects()
{
    return Adapter.GetAvailableProjects();
}
```

Translates to:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
        public virtual WebControlling.ProjectsOverallToProjectsDataTable GetAvailableProjects() {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
            WebControlling.ProjectsOverallToProjectsDataTable dataTable = new WebControlling.ProjectsOverallToProjectsDataTable();
            this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
```

Edit: When executing the query in `Query Builder` it only displays the 5 columns I want instead of 7.

Comment: What preview tool?  I think you're going to have to post your adapter code.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Preview Tool: right click anywhere in dataset designer for context menu item `Preview Data...`.

Comment: Pretty sure it's designed to include all columns. I just created a new query and didn't include all columns and first I got the warning that my query doesn't match the table's schema, then I tested with the tool and all columns showed up (5 more than I used). I don't think it's meant to be a real testing tool, just a quick-look tool. Either there really is a problem with your data or you might not be able to use the Preview tool in this case (?) with the constraints you have.

Comment: @wazz you provided the actual answer.